# Webpack ES6 Module - fancyBox / tagsInput is not a function - library import

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am trying to load to load a couple of libraries, fancyBox and tagsInput, that both depend on Jquery, into my webpack bundled es6 module.

In myFile.js, i have the following

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import './../..vendor/jquery.fancybox.js';
```

My file structure is as follows..

```
 /node_modules
 /frontend
    index.js
    /components
      /myFolder
        myFile.js
    /vendor
      jquery.fancybox.js
```

However, i am getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).fancybox is not a function
```

So it seems that fancybox is unable to attach itself to the jquery object? I am trying to rectify this by using the import loader in my webpack config below..

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const precss = require('precss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import');

module.exports = {

  context: __dirname + '/frontend',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    app: './index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static'),
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015'] } },
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap&importLoaders=1!postcss') },
    { test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]some-module[\/\\]index\.js$/, loader: 'imports?this=>window' },
    { test: /vendor\/.+\.(jsx|js)$/, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window' },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('si-styles.css'),
  ],
  postcss: function(webpack) {
    return [
      postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack }), // Must be first item in list
      precss,
      autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }),
    ];
  },

};
```

Any ideas on this would be gratefully received.

Comment: Providing jquery using webpack.ProvidePlugin in my webpack.config.js, and removing 'import jquery' from myFile seems to have fixed this.

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
        })

Answer (score 2):

Providing jquery using webpack.ProvidePlugin in my webpack.config.js, and removing 'import jquery' from myFile seems to have fixed this.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
    })
```